# Deploy website with internal asmx web service

Tags: asp.net, web-services, iis

I have a ASP.NET web site that I have created for a client. It will run hosted on their laptops via IIS for their own intranets at various locations.

In order to speed up some data intensive processes, I added a Web Service to the web site project in VS2010. Its a very simple webs service within the same namespace as the website itself.

Every runs fine in my local testing environment but not when I deploy to the users machine. I built a deployment package, so all of the files and folders are placed correctly, but when the website attempts to access the web service, I'm getting a 500 error: Web Service not found.

Do I have to start or install something via IIS Manager or is it something amiss in my webconfig?

Comment: turn off the custom errors and see what error it actually gives.

Comment: My fault. Javascript was pointing to wrong path. Installing the asmx was handled cleanly by deployment package.